# Why am I getting a NumberFormatException when I try to add values to an array of Shapes

Tags: java

I am trying to create an array of Shape Objects but when I try I am getting a NumberFormatException: For input string: "Cylinder"

Shape[] shh = new Shape[(int) numberOfShapes];

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= shapes.length; i++) {
        if (shapes[i].equals("Cylinder")) {
            shh[i] = new Cylinder();
            ((Cylinder)shh[i]).setHeight(Double.parseDouble(shapes[i++]));
            ((Cylinder)shh[i]).setRadius(Double.parseDouble(shapes[i++]));
        }
        else if(shapes[i].equals("Cone")) { 
            shh[i] = new Cone();
            ((Cone)shh[i]).setHeight(Double.parseDouble(shapes[i++]));
            ((Cone)shh[i]).setRadius(Double.parseDouble(shapes[i++]));
        }
        else if (shapes[i].equals("OctagonalPrism")) {      
            shh[i] = new OctagonalPrism();
            ((OctagonalPrism)shh[i]).setHeight(Double.parseDouble(shapes[i++]));
            ((OctagonalPrism)shh[i]).setEdgeLength(Double.parseDouble(shapes[i++]));
            }
        else if(shapes[i].equals("PentagonalPrism")) {  
            shh[i] = new PentagonalPrism();
            ((PentagonalPrism)shh[i]).setHeight(Double.parseDouble(shapes[i++]));
            ((PentagonalPrism)shh[i]).setEdgeLength(Double.parseDouble(shapes[i++]));
        }
        else if(shapes[i].equals("Pyramid")) {  
            shh[i] = new Pyramid();
            ((Pyramid)shh[i]).setHeight(Double.parseDouble(shapes[i++]));
            ((Pyramid)shh[i]).setEdgeLength(Double.parseDouble(shapes[i++]));
        }
        else if(shapes[8].equals("SquarePrism")) {  
            shh[i] = new SquarePrism();
            ((SquarePrism)shh[i]).setHeight(Double.parseDouble(shapes[i++]));
            ((SquarePrism)shh[i]).setEdgeLength(Double.parseDouble(shapes[i++]));
        }
        else if(shapes[i].equals("TriangularPrism")) {  
            shh[i] = new TriangularPrism();
            ((TriangularPrism)shh[i]).setHeight(Double.parseDouble(shapes[i++]));
            ((TriangularPrism)shh[i]).setEdgeLength(Double.parseDouble(shapes[i++]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: when do you print `shapes[i++]` what do you get a number? like `Double.parseDouble("1")`?

Comment: What `shapes` object is supposed to contain?

Comment: what would be contains? in attr or toString? so you need to do `Double.parseDouble(shapes[i++].getAttrNumber())` right? this dosent work `Double.parseDouble("aaaa")`. this will work `Double.parseDouble("1")`

Comment: Im not printing shapes[i++] at any point, if I print out shapes[i++] I get a string of Cylinder, the array im grabbing from goes like "Cylinder" "2567.09" "2345.99" "Cone" "2222.22" "2222.3". Its the shape, followed by its height and radius. Currently im reading in a text file that has that information and ive stored them in a String[] and im trying to store each shape in a Shape[], the Double.ParseDouble is converting the 2 strings into doubles so I can set the height and radius of the shapes.

Comment: if `shapes` has somehing like `[0]="name" [1]=height [2]=radius` check if happens `Double.parseDouble(shapes[0])` in any time. I think in any time `shapes[i++]` is returning the word "Cylinder" then is throwing a error on `Double.parseDouble("Cylinder")` sorry if I am wrong